# Scrape only one Anchor with same class simplehtmldom

Tags: php, dom, web-scraping

I am trying to return only one anchor with the same class name using simplehtmldom, at the moment it returns all the anchors in the page because they all have the same class name.

Here's what I am using:

```
foreach($html->find('a.db-link') as $link) {
echo $link->href . '<br>';
echo $link->plaintext . '<br>';
}
```

From the above I get:

```
http://example.com
link 1
http://example.com/2
link 2
http://example.com/3
link 3
```

I tried using the find element:

```
echo $link->find('text', 0);
```

That didn't work.

How can I just get the first anchor?

Comment: add a break; after you check that $link->href is not empty for ex

Comment: @KA_lin dont understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, it's tested:

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = str_get_html('
<a class="db-link" href="https://www.google.com/1">Google 1</a>
<a class="db-link" href="https://www.google.com/2">Google 2</a>
<a class="db-link" href="https://www.google.com/3">Google 3</a>
<a class="db-link" href="https://www.google.com/4">Google 4</a>
<a class="db-link" href="https://www.google.com/5">Google 5</a>
');


echo $html->find('a.db-link', 0);
```

### Result:

Google 1